# Add function to existing JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to add a function to a plugin without modifying the actual plugin? Can I do something like this in my site's js file?

```
$.fn.Watermark.Refresh = function() {
        $.Watermark.HideAll();
        $.Watermark.ShowAll();
    }
```

or

```
(function($){
$.fn.Watermark.Refresh = function() {
        $.Watermark.HideAll();
        $.Watermark.ShowAll();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

neither worked, the first says $ is undefined, the second that jQuery is undefined...

ideas?

Solution: Either method works, just include the jquery file before the site js file.

Comment: You should clarify what exactly it is that you want those additional functions to do.  How do you want to call them?  How are they supposed to interact with existing functions of the plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was even less clear than you thought... I want to define a function called Refresh that calls both HideAll and ShowAll. I know I can just create a standard javascript function to do this, but I thought it would be good to add it in as a function of the pluggin. It's a functionality the pluggin should really have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add those functions if you want to, but you'll have to make sure that you're also loading jQuery itself and the plugin to be modified. If you're getting those errors (that jQuery or "$" are not defined), then you have not correctly done that.

Now, though it's true that you can add those functions, I have to wonder what the point would be. If I were to do this, for example:

```
$.fn.css.myFunction = function() { return "hello world"; };
```

then it would be possible to call it:

```
var str = $.fn.css.myFunction();
```

but so what?  What good does that do me?  I don't think it's very useful.

Comment: that's what I was thinking, but jQuery is most definitely included as my entire site is done in Jquery/Jquery UI

Comment: Well, note that scripts on pages are evaluated *in the order that they are referenced*.  If your code comes *before* the script tags that import jQuery and the plugin, then you get those errors.

Comment: yup, realized that as you were posting your comment. I was including my site.js file before the jquery.js file.

Comment: And it looks like either of my two methods in my question work perfect so long as the jquery.js is included before the site.js. Thanks!

Comment: @kralco626 - the second method is preferred and recommended. Creating a closure for your plugin is much better, giving your plugin its own scope to have fun in and at the same time being able to use $ without compatibility issues.

Comment: @Marcus - noted. I will do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including the plugin *after* jQuery.