# jQuery adding function to a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, jquery-plugins

Hey all I have a plugin called **[searchableSelect](https://github.com/davidqhr/searchableSelect/blob/master/jquery.searchableSelect.js)** that I am trying to **add** a function to in order to hopefully clear the selected value in a dropdown box on the page.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/102440/)**

Here is a snip of that code and my added function:

```
(function ($) {
    // a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector
    $.expr[":"].searchableSelectContains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
        return function (elem) {
            return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        };
    });

    $.searchableSelect = function (element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = options || {};
        this.init();

        var _this = this;

        this.searchableElement.click(function (event) {
            // event.stopPropagation();
            _this.show();
        }).on('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13 || event.which === 40 || event.which == 38) {
                event.preventDefault();
                _this.show();
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', null, function (event) {
            if (_this.searchableElement.has($(event.target)).length === 0)
                _this.hide();
        });

        this.input.on('keydown', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            if (event.which === 13) {         //enter
                event.preventDefault();
                _this.selectCurrentHoverItem();
                _this.hide();
            } else if (event.which == 27) { //ese
                _this.hide();
            } else if (event.which == 40) { //down
                _this.hoverNextItem();
            } else if (event.which == 38) { //up
                _this.hoverPreviousItem();
            }
        }).on('keyup', function (event) {
            if (event.which != 13 && event.which != 27 && event.which != 38 && event.which != 40) {
                if (_this.input[1].value != "") {
                    $('#ddHeader').slideUp('slow');
                } else {
                    $('#ddHeader').slideDown('slow');
                }
            }

            _this.filter();
        })
    }

    var $sS = $.searchableSelect;

    $sS.fn = $sS.prototype = {
        version: '0.0.1'
    };

    $sS.fn.extend = $sS.extend = $.extend;
    $sS.fn.extend({
        init: function () {
            [lots of code here]...
        },
        hoverFirstNotHideItem: function () {
            this.hoverItem(this.items.find('.searchable-select-item:not(.searchable-select-hide)').first());
        },
        testing: function () {
            alert(this);
        },
        show: function () {
            this.dropdown.removeClass('searchable-select-hide');
            this.input.focus();
            this.status = 'show';
            this.setPriviousAndNextVisibility();
        },
        hide: function () {
            if (!(this.status === 'show'))
                return;

            if (this.items.find(':not(.searchable-select-hide)').length === 0)
                this.input.val('');
            this.dropdown.addClass('searchable-select-hide');
            this.searchableElement.trigger('focus');
            this.status = 'hide';
        },
        [etc etc......]
    });

    $.fn.searchableSelect = function (options) {
        this.each(function () {
            var sS = new $sS($(this), options);
        });

        //Called here because it would not get the special select boxes
        //and change their color to requiered if it needs it.
        callAllReqInput(options);

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

My added function is the **testing:** part that should fire off a alert box whenever I call that function - however, that does not happen.

I've tried the following commands to fire that function off:

> $('#networkaddress').testing
>
> $('#networkaddress').testing()
>
> $sS.testing
>
> $sS.testing()
>
> $sS.fn.testing()
>
> $sS.fn.testing
>
> $('#networkaddress').searchableSelect().testing()
>
> $('#networkaddress').searchableSelect().testing
>
> $('#networkaddress').searchableSelect.testing()
>
> $('#networkaddress').searchableSelect.testing

And that either yields an **undefined** or error.

The way I am currently firing off the actual **searchableSelect** is this way:

```
//Add search option to dropdown boxes
$('#networkaddress').searchableSelect({
});
```

I've also tried defining that above as a variable like this:

```
var blah = $('#networkaddress').searchableSelect({
            });
```

And trying these calls:

> Blah.testing()
>
> Blah.testing

Which yields the same results as the above tries.

So, what am I missing?

**Not** a dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658130/add-function-to-existing-jquery-plugin).

Comment: If you want to be able to call the function from outside the plugin you'll have to expose it in some fashion. If you're only looking to call it from within the plugin then you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @Ghostrydr I am wanting to call it outside of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The basics of what you're going to want to do is

```
$.searchableSelect = function (element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = options || {};

    if(typeof this.options === 'string') {
        // where options is the name of our function
        this[options]();
        return;
    }

    this.init();

    var _this = this

    ...
}
```

Then call it like

```
$('#networkaddress').searchableSelect('testing');
```

https://github.com/jnicol/jquery-plugin-boilerplate demonstrates this a little better, and is more robust.

Comment: So... place the function within the if statement?

Comment: No, that's just the call site. This pattern allows you to expose other functions as well. You should be able to leave you function declaration where it is.

Comment: I placed the if statement into the code and tried it again but it's still not alerting me.

Comment: Can you put together a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've updated the solution. I wrongly put `this.element` when I should've put `this.options`.  Also, in your example you're still trying to call it like this `$('#networkaddress').testing();` where you should be calling it like this `$('#networkaddress').searchableSelect('testing');`

Comment: That seems to work but **doubles** the select box everytime. **https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/108543/**

Comment: Need to add a return to the if, and move it up above this.init() like so jsfiddle.net/osw6oebv (I've also updated the solution here)